# How to create a swipe view, with bounce animation, like AirBnB? [React-Native]

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a swift developer and recently I had to move to react-native.
I'm struggling to create a swipe up and down view like in AirBnB (on the map) where there's a bottom bounce animation when you try to swipe down the view and the same for the up.
This is what I've done, but it works not so good.
Here an image of what I mean:[image: AirBnB]

```
    export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const position = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 50 });
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,

      onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
        let yPosition = gesture.dy;

        if (yPosition < 0) {
        } else {
          position.setValue({ x: 0, y: gesture.dy });
        }
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (event, gesture) => {
        Animated.spring(this.state.position, {
          toValue: { x: 0, y: 50 },
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
      },
    });
    this.state = { panResponder, position };
    this.state.position.setOffset({
      y: 50,
    });
    }
    render() {
      return //other code
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            transform: [{ translateY: this.state.position.y }],
          }}
          {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
        //view to move
        </Animated.View>
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions? Feel free to share me some links to PanGesture or something like that, but please not the official documentation, because I've already read it and it's so unclear.
Thanks

Comment: Do you need something like [that](https://snack.expo.io/_uZ5kh1lj)?

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it really bugged, can you suggest me a place where can I learn deeper animations and gestures? thank you

Comment: Of course, it has bugs, it's just a demonstration. My advice is to use **react-native-reanimated** with **react-native-gesture-handler** instead of PanResponder and React-Native Animated API because it runs on the native side and doesn't block UI thread and works perfectly with 60 fps. But official documentation isn't for beginners and won't give you anything. You can start from [here](https://codedaily.io/courses/7/React-Native-Reanimated-Fundamentals). It's a good place where you can start using animations with reanimated.